# standalone library for OpenOffice formula renderer?

Tags: math, rendering

Is there a standalone library of [OpenOffice's formula renderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_Math)? I'm looking for something that can take plain text (e.g. `E = mc^2`) in the same syntax as used by OpenOffice, and convert to png or pdf fragments.

(note: I don't need the WYSIWYG editor, just the renderer. Basically I would like to work in OpenOffice to interactively edit my formulas, and then copy the source text for use in other contexts w/o needing OpenOffice to render them.)

Comment: Would you consider latex? Which has a very good support and you can convert it to any format.

Comment: @hwlau: Good idea, but no. TeX / LateX, despite their prevalence, are far larger than I want to deal with.

Comment: Changed my mind in the intervening years. I now use MathJax frequently. I am no longer interested in answers to this question --- sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. However, I believe that my answer has covered your original question sufficiently, so it might deserve some points :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `unoconv` to convert OpenOffice/LibreOffice document to PDF.

However, first I had to create some input document with a formula.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to use just the formula editor to create ODF file because the output PDF file would contain weird headers and footers.

Therefore, I created a simple text document (in Writer) and embedded the formula as a single object (aligned as a character). I saved the ODT file, unzipped it (since ODT is just a ZIP) and edited the content. Then, I identified what files can be deleted and formatted the remaining files to get a minimal example.

In my example, the formula itself is located in `Formula/content.xml`. It should be easy to change just the code within the `<annotation>...</annotation>` tags in an automated way.

Finally, I zipped the directory and produced a new ODT file.
Then, using `unoconv` and `pdfcrop`, I produced a nice formula as PDF.

[image]

```sh
# this trick prevents zip from creating an additional directory
cd formula.odt.unzipped
zip -r ../formula.odt .
cd ..

unoconv -f pdf formula.odt  # ODT to PDF
pdfcrop formula.pdf         # keep only the formula

# you can convert the PDF to bitmap as follows
convert -density 300x300 formula-crop.pdf formula.png
```

#### Content of the unzipped ODT directory:

Here is the minimal content of an ODT file `formula.odt`.

```
formula.odt.unzipped/Formula/content.xml
formula.odt.unzipped/META-INF/manifest.xml
formula.odt.unzipped/content.xml
```

#### File `formula.odt.unzipped/Formula/content.xml` contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <semantics>
    <annotation encoding="StarMath 5.0">
        f ( x ) = sum from { { i = 0 } } to { infinity } { {f^{(i)}(0)} over {i!} x^i}
    </annotation>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

#### File `formula.odt.unzipped/content.xml` contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content
    xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
    xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
    xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <office:body>
    <office:text>
      <text:p>
        <draw:frame>
          <draw:object xlink:href="./Formula"/>
        </draw:frame>
      </text:p>
    </office:text>
  </office:body>

</office:document-content>
```

#### File `formula.odt.unzipped/META-INF/manifest.xml` contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest:manifest xmlns:manifest="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:manifest:1.0" manifest:version="1.2">
 <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="/" manifest:version="1.2" manifest:media-type="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"/>
 <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="content.xml" manifest:media-type="text/xml"/>
 <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="Formula/content.xml" manifest:media-type="text/xml"/>
 <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="Formula/" manifest:version="1.2" manifest:media-type="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula"/>
</manifest:manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several web services that run LaTeX for you and return an image. For instance, http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/

Comment: thanks, but I'm not interested either in LaTeX (I specifically want the same syntax as OpenOffice's formula editor) or a web service.